# Very simple demonstration of Backward Compatibility

Tags: python, backwards-compatibility

I just want to clarify my concept about backward compatibility, for which I have created a small example. This example is not intended to show any real use and I have ignored all other aspects of the program to keep it as simple as possible.

If there is a function in the first version of an application:

```
def print_data(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            print item
```

Which can be used like:

```
data_to_print = ['one','two','three','four','five']
print_data(data_to_print)
```

And in the next version the implementation changes to support Strings

```
def print_data(data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            print item
    elif isinstance(data, str):
        print_data(data.split())
```

so now it can be used in two ways:

```
# old style
data_to_print = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
print_data(data_to_print)

# new style
data_to_print = "one two three four five"
print_data(data_to_print)
```

can this be called a valid example of backward compatibility?

If not please give a simple example for the same.

Comment: The new version would break applications which were using `print_data` as a way to pass parameters and only print them if they are arrays and silently ignore strings. In that sense, it's not backwards compatible. If you were to add a new method `print_string_data` that would be backwards compatible because existing code wouldn't be using that method anyway.

Comment: Does it still work with the previous use if the function? If yes then the newer version is backward compatible.  This case the update is backward compatible since anything using the function with a list would get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

[See the wikipedia page about backward compatibilty.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility)

As far as your example is concerned, it would mean that data changes its format from `list` to `string` accross the whole software and for backward compatibilty reasons, `print_data` would still allow for the case where `data` is in its previous list format.